# File upload with data using Angular, node js, multer

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

Sending other fields not working with file. In Node JS only I'm receiving the file, not other formdata.

Follow the code from following link: https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-15-node-express-file-upload/
Node JS: https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-express-file-upload/

Only things need to do at the time of sending other data with file, make sure you initialized other data before initializing file in FormData:

```
formData.append('token', this.ses.token);
formData.append('random', (Math.random() * 99999).toString());
formData.append('file', file);
```

Then only it works. Still don't know what is the reason behind it